# Java: Delete the unzipped files after Zipping

Tags: java, delete-file

I have a folder `C:/path` which initially contains `abc.xml, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, xyz.html, xyz1.html` etc. and after running java zipping program my folder contains `ABC.zip, abc.xml, img1.jpg, img2.jpg, xyz.html, xyz1.html` while I want only `C:/path/ABC.zip` to be there and rest of the files should be deleted. How can I delete those files after creating the zip folder.
Thanking you.

Comment: So after you create the zip, loop through `files` again and delete them. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: So basically, what you're saying is: your question has *nothing* to do with *zipping* files in Java. It has to do with **deleting** files in Java.  If that is the case, a quick [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+delete+file) will lead you right to [`File.delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()). Try to ask more concise questions.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart OK, actually I didn't know that that it has nothing to do with zipping the files in Java. I'll edit the tags. However, in the question title I have mentioned 'Delete the files' and as I was generating a zipped folder inside the same folder so I wasn't sure if that zipped folder also gets deleted after applying File.delete(), so put up a question here. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, once you're satisfied that the zip file has been created successfully, take you `listFiles` and iterate through them calling the `delete` method.

```
//... all files zipped

for (File file : listFiles) {
    if (!file.delete()) {
      file.deleteOnExit();
    }
}

//... remove the parent folder if you wish, the same way as above
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I'm going to apply the method mentioned by you. :)

Comment: Just make sure you don't delete the files BEFORE you satisfied that the zip has been created properly ;)

Comment: Yes, I have taken care of. Also cross-checked after your comment again. :)